# Bot don't add emoji to message

Tags: python, discord.py, bots, roles

I'm newbie in Python and tried to add reaction-roles for my discord bot, but my bot succesfully  send message, but don't add emoji to message.

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.lower().startswith("!lol"):
        embed1 = discord.Embed(
            title="Escolha seu Elo!",
            color=COR,
            description="- Ferro = \n"
                        "- Bronze = \n"
                        "- Prata  =   \n"
                        "- Ouro  = \n"
                        "- Platina = \n"
                        "- Diamante = ✋\n"
                        "- Mestre = \n"
                        "- Grã-Mestre = ✊\n"
                        "- Desafiante = \n",)

    botmsg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed1)

    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "✋")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "✊")
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")

    global msg_id
    msg_id = botmsg.id

    global msg_user
    msg_user = message.author
```

This is the error i get I have tried many work arounds with this I can't find anything that will fix this issue

```
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 55, in on_message
    botmsg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed1)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'embed1' referenced before assignment
Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/virtualenvs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 343, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "main.py", line 57, in on_message
    await ctx.message.add_reaction(botmsg, "")
NameError: name 'ctx' is not defined
```

Also I tried use

```
emoji = client.get_emoji(310177266011340803)
await message.add_reaction(emoji)
```

But this don't work too

upd: These emoji is example, I wanna use both unicode emoji and custom emoji

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content.lower().startswith("!lol"):
        embed1 = discord.Embed(
            title="Escolha seu Elo!",
            color=COR,
            description="- Ferro = \n"
                        "- Bronze = \n"
                        "- Prata  =   \n"
                        "- Ouro  = \n"
                        "- Platina = \n"
                        "- Diamante = ✋\n"
                        "- Mestre = \n"
                        "- Grã-Mestre = ✊\n"
                        "- Desafiante = \n",)

    botmsg = await message.channel.send(embed=embed1)

    await botmsg.add_reaction("")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("✋")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("✊")
    await botmsg.add_reaction("")

    global msg_id
    msg_id = botmsg.id

    global msg_user
    msg_user = message.author
```

The context arg is not passed when `on_message` is called. Instead of `ctx.message.add_reaction()` you can use `message.add_reaction()`.
EDIT: Oh I understand your full problem, now the script should react to your bot's message.

Comment: Thank you, you're the best